# Почему не работает привязка данных?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

```
<ModelVisual3D x:Class="OrbitalSimulator.View.OrbitModelVisual3D"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="Model">
<ModelVisual3D.Transform>
    <Transform3DGroup>
        <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding Scale.X, ElementName=Model}"
                          ScaleY="{Binding Scale.Y, ElementName=Model}"
                          ScaleZ="{Binding Scale.Z, ElementName=Model}"/>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding EulerAngles.Yaw, ElementName=Model}" Axis="0 0 1" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding EulerAngles.Pitch, ElementName=Model}" Axis="0 1 0" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="{Binding EulerAngles.Roll, ElementName=Model}" Axis="1 0 0" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
        <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="{Binding Radius, ElementName=Model}"/>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="{Binding OrbitAxis, ElementName=Model}"  
                                     Angle="{Binding CourseAngle, ElementName=Model}" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0 1 0" Angle="{Binding Latitude, ElementName=Model}" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0 0 1" Angle="{Binding Longitude, ElementName=Model}" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
    </Transform3DGroup>
</ModelVisual3D.Transform>
```

```
 public partial class OrbitModelVisual3D : ModelVisual3D
{
    public OrbitModelVisual3D()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Vector3D OrbitAxis
    {
        get { return (Vector3D)GetValue(OrbitAxisProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrbitAxisProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrbitAxisProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OrbitAxis", typeof(Vector3D), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));


    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));

    public EulerAngles EulerAngles
    {
        get { return (EulerAngles)GetValue(EulerAnglesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EulerAnglesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EulerAnglesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EulerAngles", typeof(EulerAngles), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));

    public Point3D Scale
    {
        get { return (Point3D)GetValue(ScaleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScaleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Scale", typeof(Point3D), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));

    public double Longitude
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LongitudeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LongitudeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongitudeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Longitude", typeof(double), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));

    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LatitudeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LatitudeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LatitudeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Latitude", typeof(double), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));

    public double CourseAngle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CourseAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CourseAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CourseAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CourseAngle", typeof(double), typeof(OrbitModelVisual3D));
}
```

Пример использования контрола:

```
<l:OrbitModelVisual3D Scale="0.005 0.005 0.005" Radius="{Binding OrbitModel.CurrentPosition.Radius}" Longitude="{Binding OrbitModel.StartPoint.Longitude}" Latitude="{Binding OrbitModel.StartPoint.Latitude}" CourseAngle="{Binding OrbitModel.CurrentPosition.OrbitAngle}" OrbitAxis="{Binding OrbitModel.OrbitAxis}">
    <t:FileModelVisual3D Source="3dsModels/tdrs_no_ants.3ds"/>
</l:OrbitModelVisual3D>
```

Программа компилируется, ни ошибок ни предупреждений не выдает, просто передаваемые данные не биндятся, но когда я вместо `ScaleX="{Binding Scale.X, ElementName=Model}` использую `ScaleX="{Binding Path=Scale.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ModelVisual3D}}}`, то все работает.

Comment: А что значит «не работает»? Не компилируется? Вылетает во время выполнения? Если работает не так, как вы ожидаете, то объясните, как вы используете контрол, и что именно происходит.

Comment: Программа компилируется, ни ошибок ни предупреждений не выдает, просто передаваемые данные не биндятся, но когда я вместо `ScaleX="{Binding Scale.X, ElementName=Model}` использую `ScaleX="{Binding Path=Scale.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ModelVisual3D}}}` и для остальных свойств соответственно, то все работает.

Comment: О, это уже другой разговор. А что выдаётся в окно Output при пробеге этого кода? Обычно ошибки в Binding'е видны в логе.

Comment: Похоже понял в чем проблема, где строчка `x:Name="Model"` пишет: "Невозможно зарегистрировать повторяющееся Name "Model" в этой области".

Comment: Хм, в коде, который вы привели, только один раз даётся имя `Model`. А если поменять `Model` на что-то другое? Или может у вас в классе `OrbitModelVisual3D` уже есть свойство `Model`?

Comment: В `OrbitModelVisual3D` нет свойства с именем Model, я этот класс привел полностью, кроме того, я попробовал присвоить другое имя для `x:Name`, вплоть до "jfjfj", все равно пишет: "Невозможно зарегистрировать повторяющееся Name "Model" в этой области"

Comment: Окно output: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Model'. BindingExpression:Path=Scale.Y; DataItem=null; target element is 'ScaleTransform3D' (HashCode=59407164); target property is 'ScaleY' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Model'. BindingExpression:Path=Scale.Z; DataItem=null; target element is 'ScaleTransform3D' (HashCode=59407164); target property is 'ScaleZ' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data ...

Comment: Хм, это уже странно. Попробуйте перекомпилироваться. Если вы не даёте нигде имя «Model», то оно не должно и появляться в выводе.

Comment: Вообщем проблема именно в x;Name, почему-то не удается его задать. Тогда вопрос в следующем, у ModelVisual3D отсутствует DataContex, а запись  `ScaleX="{Binding Path=Scale.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ModelVisual3D}}}` слишком длинная и приходится использовать ее много раз. Возможно ли другим способом решить эту проблему, например может как то самому реализовать DataContext для OrbitModelVisual3D?

Comment: А если просто `Name`, компилируется?

Comment: Если вам всё время нужно привязываться к корневому элементу, возможно, вам нужен темплейт, в котором можно привязаться через TemplateBinding. Ну это если получится задать в нём Transform.